# Почему не получается запустить приложение через docker?

Tags: php, docker, symfony

Всем привет! Пытаюсь запустить symfony приложение с помощью docker'a. Скачал с помощью composer'a api приложение symfony

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project_name
```

Создал в установленном проекте Dockerfile. Заполнил его таким содержимом

```
FROM php:7.4-cli

ADD . /opt/symfony
WORKDIR /opt/symfony

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["php", "-S", "localhost:8080", "-t", "public/"]
```

То есть по сути открывается порт `8080` и командой `php -S localhost:8080 -t public/` запускаю сервер.

Далее делаю билд этого проекта `sudo docker build -t name/symfony .`

И запускаю его `sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 name/symfony`

Получаю такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я с браузера пытаюсь перейти на localhost:8080, но получаю такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить? Почему у меня не получается получить доступ к приложению?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить `CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8080", "-t", "public/"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте запустить

```
CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8080", "-t", "public/"]
```

А еще лучше добавьте в докер файл например что то типа такого

```
RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | sudo bash && sudo mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

тем самым добавив в проект Symfony CLI и запускайте сервер

```
symfony server:start
```